# Two WAMP servers, one slow - one fast. Need a hint

Tags: php, apache, performance

I have one virtual server hosted with my local provider (Serbia) and I wanted to move it to a dedicated server at another provider (Germany), and so I leased the dedicated server for a month to try it out. 
After two weeks of testing this an that, I have hit a brick wall because I can not find why is the German server slower in network response than the Serbian. The fact is that I am testing from Serbia, but physical distance should not be a factor (or is it?).

I have noticed that the German server is slow because I used a PHP page to show data from a linked MSSQL server (2012 Express) on a third machine, and the data pulling was awfully slow.

After trying to optimize PHP,queries and trying different connection types, I tried to see if the web servers are  the same, or is it a network transfer issue, so I made one blank HTML page printing out only one word and copied the page „index.html“ to the web root of both servers, and I got different response times from both servers: Serbian ~40ms, German ~100ms.

Here are server specs and screens from Chrome loading the page:

Serbia
[Serbian server Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqXdv.png)

- OS – Win server 2012 standard 64bit
- RAM – 4GB
- CPU – Intel XEON E5620 2.4GHz
- HDD – 40GB (don’t know the type)
- WAMP – v2.2
- Apache – 2.2.21
- PHP – 5.3.10

Germany
[German server Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bay.png)

- OS – Win server 2012 R2 standard 64bit
- RAM – 64GB CPU – Intel CORE i7-6700 3.4GHz
- HDD – 250GB (SSD)
- WAMP – v2.2
- Apache – 2.2.22
- PHP – 5.3.13

Both Apaches have modules „deflate“ and „filter“ on, and the same .htaccess file on both servers.

Finally, my question is: does anyone have any idea where to look or what to try.

Comment: Distance *is* a huge factor. You said you have a third machine that you connect to - again, networking plays a huge role. Your German server is probably more powerful in terms of raw CPU power, but since you depend on network a lot, it appears it's a bottleneck. There are tools such as `ab`, `wrk` or `siege` that can help you determine potential processing power of your servers. If you assert that German one is indeed faster, then you can be 100% sure that it's responding slower because it's waiting for network task to complete.

Comment: I just didn't think distance of about 1000 km can make such a delay. And this is on empty page, not to mention if some data has to be pulled from the server.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which one (server or distance) is the problem, you can benchmark the script:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);

// your code

$duration = microtime(true) - $start;
?>
```

If you get similar times, the problem is the network.